# Deciphering which control fired an event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I have an application with many images that all look the same and perform similar tasks:

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="image_prog1_slot0" Stretch="Uniform" Source="bullet-icon.png" StretchDirection="Both" MouseDown="image_prog1_slot0_MouseDown"/>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="image_prog1_slot1" Stretch="Uniform" Source="bullet-icon.png" StretchDirection="Both" />
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="image_prog1_slot2" Stretch="Uniform" Source="bullet-icon.png" StretchDirection="Both" />
```

Now, I want to link each one to the same event handler:

```
private void image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //this_program = ???;
            //this_slot = ???;
            //slots[this_program][this_slot] = some value;
        }
```

Obviously the program number and slot number of the image are part of its name.  Is there a way to extract this information when the event handler is fired?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

As its name suggests, the `sender` parameter contains the object which fired the event.

You can also use the `Grid`'s attached properties for convenience to determine which row and column it is in. (It is also possible to get other attached properties this way.)

```
private void image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Getting the Image instance which fired the event
    Image image = (Image)sender;

    string name = image.Name;
    int row = Grid.GetRow(image);
    int column = Grid.GetRow(image);

    // Do something with it
    ...
}
```

Side note:

You can also use the `Tag` property to store custom information about controls. (It can store any objects.)

Comment: +1. It's also possible to compare 'sender' with each member variable to see which control it is