# C# Get Control how fired the event winforms

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a problem:
I have a two buttons and OnClick i call a CreateTelegram() Function in XmlHelper Class.
The function creates a Xml an send it to the server.
If the server responds (xml), an event was fired.
Now if the XML-element returnCode = 0,i will edit a Textfield Backcolor Property to Green.

how can i get the Control who fired the event (Button1 or Button2)

here my Code:

**Button1:**

```
private void btnCheckId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  xmlHelper.CreateTelegram(configSettings, txtIdCheck.Text);
}
```

**Button2:**

```
private void btnCheckId2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  xmlHelper.CreateTelegram(configSettings, txtIdCheck2.Text);
}
```

**XmlHelper:**

```
 public void CreateTelegram(ConfigSettings configSettings, string Identifier)
    {
      XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
      settings.Indent = true;
      settings.IndentChars = ("    ");
      settings.CloseOutput = true;
      //settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
      using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
      {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
        {

         xml Stuff..

        }
        
        string partTelegram = sw.ToString();

        SendTelegramm(partTelegram , configSettings.serverAddress, configSettings.serverPort);
      }
    }
```

**The Event Subscription:**

```
_connector.DataReceived += new EventHandler<SocketEventArgs<byte[]>>(Connector_DataReceived);
```

**The Connector_DataReceived function**

```
   private void Connector_DataReceived(object sender, SocketEventArgs<byte[]> e)
    {
      if (e == null || e.Repository == null)
        return;
      if (_currentMsg != null)
      {
        {
          try
          {
            _currentMsg.ResponseMessage = new XmlMessage(EvaluateReceivedData(e.Repository), false);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            ShowTextThreadProc(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
          }
          return;
        }
      }
      EvaluateReceivedData(e.Repository);
    }


private string EvaluateReceivedData(byte[] data)
{
  int offset = (int)this._connector.Offset;
  if (data == null || data.Length <= offset)
    return null;
  string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, offset, data.Length - offset);

  DisplayMessage(msg);
  return msg;
}

 private void DisplayReceivedData(string text)
    {
      try
      {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(text));


         int returnCode = Convert.ToInt32(doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/event/result/@returnCode")?.Value ?? "-1");
     
        Debug.WriteLine(returnCode );

        if (returnCode == 0)
        {
          ...GET THE SENDER and edit the BackColor...
        }


      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
      finally 
      {
        Disconnect();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Enjoy this 10 year old duplicate: [Deciphering which control fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868977/deciphering-which-control-fired-an-event)

Comment: Sorry i have two different Buttons. I edited the  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the `sender` argument:

```
private void btnCheckId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    if (clickedButton == Button1)
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry the Buttons are not the Same. The Problem is in the datareceived function how can i geht the clicked Button?

Comment: Do you mean the last clicked button? Store a reference to it. Or how is `_connector.DataReceived` connected to a button click...?

Comment: yeah the last clicked Button. Datareceived will fire If Data a Receiver from the Server.

Comment: So store `clickedButton` in a field in the class: `private Button _clickedButton;`

Comment: Okay. I thought i must use an event, but storing the clicked Button is the right way?

Comment: @Silazz1378: Event for what? You should still handle the click event of course...